# What does ret and frame mean here?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, numpy

When to use ret and frame? What values do these variables hold?
I have just started with image processing, so if there are more changes do let me know.

Thank you

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Sample Lap HUL_OB_1.56.641_Graphic.mpg')

# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
# fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'MJPG')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.mpg',0, 60.0, (640,480))
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
         # frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)
         # write the flipped frame
        out.write(frame)
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
             break
     else:
        break
# Release everything if job is finished
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-read is the first place i would look

Comment: One would think returning `frame` alone would be sufficient in Python, if an invalid frame raised an error or at least took a `None` value. I don't know why they need to return a boolean with that. It's probably because cv2 comes from C++?

Answer (score 21):

```
ret, frame = cap.read()
```

1. `ret` is a boolean variable that returns true if the frame is available.
2. `frame` is an image array vector captured based on the default frames per second defined explicitly or implicitly

Answer (score 12):

"Frame" will get the next frame in the camera (via "cap").
"Ret" will obtain return value from getting the camera frame, either true of false. I recommend you to read the OpenCV tutorials(which are highly detailed) like this one for face recognition:
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html

Answer (score 2):

That is explained in `cap.read` docs. Since `cap` is a `VideoCapture` object, using Google on "VideoCapture opencv Read" will instantly lead you to openCV's documentation. The `read` functions doc will point you to `grab` which will explain in detail `retval`:

> The methods/functions grab the next frame from video file or camera and return ...

Answer (score 1):

Please look at the documentation [here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html).

It says:

> `cap.read()` returns a bool (True/False). If frame is read correctly,
>   it will be True. So you can check end of the video by checking this
>   return value.

Answer (score 1):

ret:
ret is used to check whether the webcam is available or not (i.e.) if we open the camera application while running a OpenCV program, ret will identifies that the webcam is not available now so it will returns False and through an error.

frame:
frame is used to store the array values of respective pixels of the video